# Handling default attribute of an object of a self-written class shows weird behavior in 64Bit office

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop, 32bit-64bit

During migrating a VBA Project from 32 to 64Bit I came across the following weird behavior in Excel 2016. The code below works perfectly in Excel 32Bit.

A homemade class "clDatenKnoten" is created to handle data and do some extra stuff. 
It has a default member, that is defined as a function with return type variant, as it might return data of different types or objects depending on the context - changing it is not really an option.

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim tVar1 As New clDatenKnoten, tVar2, tVar3 As String

tVar1 = "Name=bar"          'The objects default "setter"-function processes the String and saves the value for "Name"
Set tVar2 = tVar1            

tVar3 = tVar2("Name")        'The objects default "getter"-function retrieves the value for "Name" and returns it.  
Debug.Print 1; VarType(tVar1); TypeName(tVar1)
Debug.Print 2; VarType(tVar2); TypeName(tVar2)
Debug.Print 3; VarType(tVar1("Name")); TypeName(tVar1("Name"))
Debug.Print 4; VarType(tVar2("Name")); TypeName(tVar2("Name"))

Debug.Print 5; "foo " & tVar3
Debug.Print 6; "foo " & tVar2("Name")
tVar3 = "foo " & tVar2("Name")
Debug.Print 7; tVar3

tVar3 = tVar1("Name")
Debug.Print 8; "foo " & tVar3
Debug.Print 9; "foo " & tVar1("Name")
End Sub
```

On a 32 Bit Office <= 2016 it produces the following output:

> 1  8 clDatenKnoten
>    2  8 clDatenKnoten
>    3  8 String
>    4  8 String
>    5 foo bar
>    6 foo bar
>    7 foo bar
>    8 foo bar
>    9 foo bar

However, on a 64 Bit office 2016 it produces the following:

> 1  8 clDatenKnoten
>    2  8 clDatenKnoten
>    3  8 String
>    4  8 String
>    5 foo bar
>    6 foo bar
>    7 barbar                 (sic!)
>    8 foo bar
>    9 foo bar

Line 3 is obviously quite off. It has two problems: The default function returns something weird and the weird return is processed in a weird way.
Note the difference between 2 and 3 which is like almost the same statement.

The difference between tVar1 and tVar2 is the explicit type for the former and variant for the latter. However, `?typename(tVar2)` returns `"clDatenKnoten"` correctly.

Comment: Strange. What happens in both Office versions when you print out `Debug.Print 0; VarType(tVar2("Name"))` before your first Debug statement? Be interesting to see if there's any difference there. VarType might give us more information about that Variant - [Microsoft documentation for VarType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)

Comment: Does this also happen, when you declare `tVar2` explicitely as `clDatenKnoten`?

Comment: @UnhandledException: no. With explicit types, it behaves exactly like behavior tVar1. Hence, I assume it is an issue of the loose type (Which is, however, recognized correctly by typename(tVar2) = typename(tVar1) = "clDatenKnoten".)

Comment: @Ben, sorry for the long delay. I edited the post to include the VarType (although that doesnt really help. )

Comment: I have no explanation for "7 barbar" - it seems to me like something very odd is happening at a lower level then VBA lets us see. Can you do away with the default member functionality, and just explicitly set and get from a named property, just to rule out that being a factor?

Comment: Dear Ben, indeed, if i use the named getters & setters there is no issue at all. 
For me it seems like the '&' operator is somehow corrupt in the 64Bit version, as the default function returns the correct value "bar" but the value is not corretly combined with the "foo " 
(in fact, it always results in the same behaviour: the return value of the  standard function is just concatenated twice and returned.)